# fetch path field value from nested objects(Parent- child) using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

```
var levels= [
 {
  path: 'RS',
  hasChild :true
 },
    {
     path: 'MO',
     hasChild: true
    },
       {
        path: 'EL',
        hasChild: true   
       },
          {
            path: 'CL',
            hasChild: false
          },
       {
        path: 'EL1',
        hasChild: true   
       },
          {
            path: 'CL1',
            hasChild: false
          },
{
  path: 'RS2',
  hasChild :true
 },
    {
    path: 'MO2',
    hasChild: true
    },
      {
       path: 'EL2',
       hasChild: true   
       },
          {
            path: 'CL2',
            hasChild: false
          },
          {
            path: 'CL3',
            hasChild: false
          },
];
```

Is it possible to create complete path from the object 'level' using underscore.js?
For e.g. - 
RS\MO\EL\CL
           RS\MO\EL1\CL1
           RS2\MO2\EL2\CL2
           RS2\MO2\CL3\CL3
In any of the above levels child can appear more than one. Please advise if underscore.js can do deep watching of nested array of objects.

Please apologize me for the bad formatting of nested array of objects above.

Comment: so depending upon hasChild flag you have to create your path

Comment: Yes Keval, that's right. Please note 'level' object is nested array of similar object and at any level there can be n number of childs and so on and paths should be created for each of them. I thought about doing it in recursion way but yeah was getting too complex.

Comment: if you format your json that doesn't mean it is nested json and  how you should now which is parent object

Comment: Keval - I added few more required info in your answer comments below regarding Parent object. I could have done it better though in terms of formatting. I agree.

Answer (score 1):

```
function parse (levels)  {
  var buffer = [], target = [];
  levels.forEach(function (level) {
    buffer.push(level.path);
    if (!level.hasChild) {
      target.push(buffer.join('/'));
      buffer.splice(0, buffer.length + 1);
    }
  });
  return levels;  
}
```

> Gives: **[ 'RS/MO/EL/CL', 'EL1/CL1', 'RS2/MO2/EL2/CL2', 'CL3' ]**

Given your current structure, the logic to get the desired output is unclear.
How should the program know that `RS2` starts a new node, but `EL1` doesn't?

#### EDIT:

This solve the problem, but honestly, its hacky. A better way is to structure the data in a better way.

```
function parse (levels)  {
  var buffer = [], target = [];
  levels.forEach(function (level) {
    if (level.hasChild) {
      buffer.push(level.path);
    }
    else {
      var tmp = buffer.slice();
      tmp.push(level.path);
      target.push(tmp.join('/'));
      buffer.splice(buffer.length - 1, 1);
    }
    if (/^RS/.test(level.path)) {
      buffer.splice(1, buffer.length);
    }
  });
  return target;
}
```

> Result: **['RS/MO/EL/CL', 'RS/MO/EL1/CL1', 'RS/MO2/EL2/CL2', 'RS/MO2/CL3']**

Comment: Uzi. for MO Path we have 2 childs basically and both the child need to use same parent path and I think that's the difficult part here to find out as well. there can be n children at any point in the levels, so the structure is not similar always but dynamic.

Comment: indentation don't mean anything in javascript. you need to build a better hierarchy. why does `RS2` start a new element? what is the clue?

Comment: node with RS is always going to be Parent Node. that levvel will have type: RandomSession. so I can get all Parents of leveltype.RandomSessions . For above e.g. I will get two Child of RS type and both will be Parent Node for all the paths

Comment: How do you know that programmatically? by the path string? can you define the algorithm in words, so we understand what the requirements are?

Comment: Requirement is to get all available paths, which starts from RS nodes( type of: RandomSessions). Each RS node can have 1 on n number of childNodes and each of these child can have 1 or n number of childs. but always RS is going to be parent of each path.

Comment: Uzi and Keval appreciate your help. As suggested I will restructure my data and see if it helps.. its better I do it now unless code will be messy.

Comment: a +1 will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use _.each for that

```
var path =""

_.each(levels,function(object){

 path = path +object.path+"/"
})
console.log(path)
```

> Output:**"RS/MO/EL/CL/EL1/CL1/RS2/MO2/EL2/CL2/CL3/"**

Edit:

I think your Json shoud be like this:

```
var levels = [
        {
        "path": "RS",
        "hasChild": true,
        "childerens": {
            "path": "MO",
            "hasChild": true,
            "childe1": [
                {
                    "path": "EL",
                    "hasChild": true
                },
                {
                    "path": "CL",
                    "hasChild": false
                }
            ],
            "childe2": [
                {
                    "path": "EL1",
                    "hasChild": true
                },
                {
                    "path": "CL1",
                    "hasChild": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "isParent": true
    },
    {
        "path": "RS2",
        "hasChild": true,
        "childerens": {
            "path": "MO2",
            "hasChild": true,
            "chiled1": [
                {
                    "path": "EL2",
                    "hasChild": true
                },
                {
                    "path": "CL2",
                    "hasChild": false
                }
            ],
            "chiled2": [
                {
                    "path": "CL3",
                    "hasChild": true
                },
                {
                    "path": "CL3",
                    "hasChild": false
                }
            ]
        },
        "isParent": true
    }
]
```

For validate json is wrong or right go to [JSONLINT](http://jsonlint.com/)

> Remove variable name for validation

Comment: in your edited quetion how you should now which one is your parent node

Comment: node with RS is always going to be Parent Node. Say the object will have type: RandomSession. so I can get all Parents of leveltype.RandomSessions . For above e.g. I will get two Child of RS type

Comment: i created json in console so if you want to create this type of json and need any help let me know